Use a project as custom template in Gitlab
I'm new to GitLab, and I need to use a project as a template for creating multiple projects with the same structure. But when I go to the general settings of my project, the "template" option doesn't exist. Is this feature only available to Ultimate users? Am I doing something wrong? Was I supposed to do something during the creation of the project to make GitLab let me use it as a template?
My settings view
I tried exporting the project. I also tried using a public project and searched through all the options. I was expecting this option to be available, like in the tutorials.
Tutorial template settings

Yes

Tier: Premium, Ultimate

from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/custom_project_templates.html
`
